# Two VBA codes needed to paste in same unused row

Tags: vba, excel

I need these two sets of VBA to paste on same line instead of one line below each other.The problem is they both look for an unused row, which is needed, but they should be on the same unused row. Thanks.

```
Sub Macro10()
Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("A = B4", "B = B5", "C = J5")
Dim Row As Long
Row = Worksheets("Customer List").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
For Each trans In refTable
Dim Dest As String, Field As String
Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
Worksheets("Customer List").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("Order Entry").Range(Field).Value
Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Order Entry")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Customer List")

copySheet.Range("A8:K22").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is the Macro that Calls both of these macros.

```
Sub SUBMIT()
    Call Macro10
    Call CommandButton1_Click
    Call Check
    Call Macro6
    Call Macro12
End Sub
```

Comment: How is `Macro10` called?

Comment: @Gareth I have a seperate macro that calls both of these macros, macro 10 before CommandButton1_Click()

Comment: You probably wanting to assign to a variable prior to calling the macros and passing the variable into them. Could you update with the code that calls these macros?

Comment: @Gareth Updated with code

Comment: My eyes hurt. Don't use copy and paste, assign values with `.Value` in a range defined with `Range("A1").Resize(12,8).Value = Range("A1").Offset(0,10).Resize(12,8).Value` for example. Also use name ranges and not hard code "A8:K22". You are begging for a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a function that funds the row and save the as a variable.  Create a function that saves the row as an integer and use this value in both subs.

```
 Function findEmptyRow() As Integer
    Row = Worksheets("Customer List").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
 End Function

 Sub SUBMIT()
     row = findEmptyRow()
     Call Macro10(row)
     Call CommandButton1_Click(row)
     Call Check
     Call Macro6
     Call Macro12
 End Sub
```

Amend Macro10 so it can accept variables

```
Sub Macro10(row As Integer)
Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("A = B4", "B = B5", "C = J5")

For Each trans In refTable
    Dim Dest As String, Field As String
    Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & row
    Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
    Worksheets("Customer List").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("Order Entry").Range(Field).Value
Next
```

End Sub

Then similar for CommandButton1_Click.  This used a different method to find the empty row so it has to be adjusted slightly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(row As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Order Entry")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Customer List")

copySheet.Range("A8:K22").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So I would just need to add "row as Integer" and delete pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues out of CommandButton1_Click

Comment: I amended my answer to provide the code for the other sub.  Test it out and let me know if it causes an error.

Comment: I am getting a Compile error:ByRef argument type mismatch on Call Macro10(row)

Comment: row should be defined as integer, not long.  It needs to be the same in all places.  You can use long is you will use more than 32,000 rows, which is not uncommon.